# No property date found for type cashflow in Springboot app

Tags: spring-boot, service, repository, entity, spring-restcontroller

I am writing a rest service on cashflow entity with entity, repository, service, controller design patern.

**Entity:-**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cashflow")
public class Cashflow implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    @NotBlank
    private String entityId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String companyId;

    @Column
    private boolean isDeleted = true;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    public void setEntityId(String entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }

    public String getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(String companyId) {
        this.companyId = companyId;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

}
```

**Repository:-**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CashflowRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Cashflow, Long> {
    Page<Cashflow> findAllByCompanyIdAndIsDeleted(String companyId, boolean flag, Pageable pageable);

    public Cashflow findByEntityId(String entityId);

    public List<Cashflow> findAllByEntityIdIn(List<String> entityIds);
}
```

**Service:-**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CashflowService {

    @Autowired
    private CashflowRepository cashflowRepository;

    public Page<Cashflow> findByCompanyId(String companyId, Integer pageNo, Integer pageSize, String sortBy) {
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize, Sort.by(sortBy));
        Page<Cashflow> pagedResult = cashflowRepository.findAllByCompanyIdAndIsDeleted(companyId, false, paging);
        return pagedResult;
    }
}
```

**Controller:-**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class CashflowController {

    @Autowired
    private CashflowService cashflowService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{companyId}/settlement/cashflows")
    public Page<Cashflow> findParcels(@PathVariable("companyId") String companyId, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer pageNo, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") Integer pageSize, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "date") String sortBy) {
        return cashflowService.findByCompanyId(companyId, pageNo, pageSize, sortBy);
    }

}
```

When I am calling the service it's giving following error:-

> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property date found for type Cashflow!    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:94)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toJpaOrder(QueryUtils.java:565)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toOrders(QueryUtils.java:518)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:197)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:150)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.complete(JpaQueryCreator.java:57)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.createQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:164)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:94)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:210)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:199)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy234.findAllByCompanyIdAndIsDeleted(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.cstar.api.settlement.CashflowService.findByCompanyId(CashflowService.java:18)
>   ~[main/:na]   at
>   com.cstar.api.settlement.CashflowController.findParcels(CashflowController.java:20)
>   ~[main/:na]   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   com.cstar.api.config.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:75)
>   ~[main/:na]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]    at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]

I have built REST apis based on same design pattern and it worked fine for me. I am not getting on thing, why it says "No property **date** found for type Cashflow!"? There is no date property in the Entity anyway. I tried dropping the database and starting again, didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: You are sending a request with an `orderBy` named `date`. Your incoming request includes invalid attribute names

Comment: Yes I copied that code from another class and totally missed out on changing that. Please give the answe in answers in stead of comments section so thta I can accept it as correct answer. It will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stracktrace tells you what the problem is

```
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE] at 
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE] at
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toJpaOrder(QueryUtils.java:565) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE] at
 org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toOrders(QueryUtils.java:518) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE] at
```

This clearly states that when generating the ordering clause it breaks on an unknown property. The ordering is done based in the passed in `Pageable` which you construct in your controller. The construction depends on a passed in request parameter `sortBy`, which has a default value of `date`.

Now when the parameter isn't present this value is used, as your entity doesn't have a `date` property it will break.

Either remove the ordering or provide a valid default.